# Symfony2 auto generating entities error.

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i have two tables news and news_category. for that i have created two mapping class using symfony command 'doctrine:mapping:convert'. the two file as bellow.

1. news.orm.yml.

   ```
   News:
      type: entity
      table: news
      fields:
         newsId:
             id: true
             type: integer
             unsigned: false
             nullable: false
             column: news_id
             generator:
                  strategy: IDENTITY
        newsTitle:
            type: string
            length: 255
            fixed: false
            nullable: false
            column: news_title
        newsDescription:
            type: text
            nullable: false
            column: news_description
        newsStatus:
            type: string
            length: 255
            fixed: false
            nullable: false
            column: news_status
        createdAt:
            type: date
            nullable: false
            column: created_at
       manyToOne:
       category:
            targetEntity: NewsCategory
            cascade: {  }
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
               category_id:
                   referencedColumnName: category_id
            orphanRemoval: false
   lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
   ```

2). NewCategory.orm.yml

```
NewsCategory:
type: entity
table: news_category
fields:
    categoryId:
        id: true
        type: integer
        unsigned: false
        nullable: false
        column: category_id
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
    categoryTitle:
        type: string
        length: 255
        fixed: false
        nullable: false
        column: category_title
    categoryDescription:
        type: text
        nullable: false
        column: category_description
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

after that i have used the another symfony command "doctrine:mapping:import" using this i have again generate two file in Entity folder News.php and NewsCategory.php

which is as bellow.

1) news.php

```
<?php

  namespace Admin\NewsBundle\Entity;

  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 /**
  * News
  *
  * @ORM\Table(name="news")
  * @ORM\Entity
  */
  class News
 {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="news_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $newsId;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="news_title", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $newsTitle;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="news_description", type="text", nullable=false)
 */
private $newsDescription;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="news_status", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $newsStatus;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="date", nullable=false)
 */
private $createdAt;

/**
 * @var \NewsCategory
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="NewsCategory")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="category_id")
 * })
 */
private $category;

}
```

And, 2) NewCategory.php

```
namespace Admin\NewsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * NewsCategory
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="news_category")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class NewsCategory
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="category_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $categoryId;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="category_title", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $categoryTitle;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="category_description", type="text", nullable=false)
 */
private $categoryDescription;

}
```

the problem is now when i am creating the Entities using the "doctrine:generate:entities"
it is giving me the following error.

```
D:\wamp\www\Symfony>php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AdminNewsBundle
Generating entities for bundle "AdminNewsBundle"

  [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
  Invalid mapping file 'Admin.NewsBundle.Entity.News.orm.yml' for class 'Admi
  n\NewsBundle\Entity\News'.

 doctrine:generate:entities [--path="..."] [--no-backup] name
```

sorry for poor english please help me out come from this problem as i am new to symfony2

Comment: You don't need to generate `Annotations` if you're using `yml` mapping. Try to delete your entities and run the command again. Also, make sure that your YML files are correctly indented. The ones you provided are incorrect. *(See manyToOne in `news.orm.yml`)*

Comment: yes my yml file is correctly indented becoz it is generated dinmical i have deleted my entity but still not creating entities. thanks for replay.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
1) php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/Admin/NewsBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force --namespace="Admin\\NewsBundle\\Entity\\"
```

for Linux *namespace="Admin\\NewsBundle\\Entity\\"*, for Win probably *namespace="Admin\NewsBundle\Entity\\"*

Watch that mapping is in right place, has correct names and correct syntax.

```
2) php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AdminNewsBundle annotation

3) php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AdminNewsBundle
```

Comment: i don't know how this "." comming in the file name Admin.NewsBundle.Entity.News.orm.yml

Comment: try to remove this '.', and then generate.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the first line of YML with the entity name with naspace

```
Admin\NewsBundle\Entity\News:
```

for exemple.